# youtube url modifiers

Tags: youtube, http-headers

So i am currently working on some scripts that will automatically upload videos to youtube from my blogs

problem is that some of the headers that are being sent are really quirky

for example, several of the s.youtube.com headers look something like this

```
https://s.youtube.com/s?tspne=0&md=1&len=349.115&csipt=watch5&el=detailpage&docid=suwLPxSNY1o&vid=eCiOBX5XBsoFE9Fx2fQ1mBZNDQGSG2gjC&hasstoryboard=1&nsivbblmax=110096.000&sd=B4A7D6725HH1335401360395385&volume=100&h=360&nsivbblmin=56688.000&bd=4876439&bt=40.967&nsivbblmean=84292.823&tabsb=1&nsivbblc=316&nsiabblmax=163000.000&w=480&nsiabblmin=143990.000&plid=AAS-ilsb9hm3dPf3&cfps=8.94454382826476&fmt=34&nsiabblmean=157694.108&screenh=768&nsiabblc=316&playerw=640&hl=en_US&screenw=1366&playerh=390&scoville=1&pd=0.710&mos=0&vtmp=1&fexp=904542,906030&referrer=None&fs=0&sendtmp=1&rt=112.686&vq=auto&lact=115762&vw=480&ns=yt&vh=360&et=109.9&rendering=software&st=70.304&decoding=accelerated&hbd=1188672&tsphab=1&hbt=0.778&nsidf=24&tspfdt=1158&bc=19023019&cr=US
```

i know some of the basic url modifiers for example
len refers to the length of the video
cr refers to the country
but can someone shed some knowledge on what the rest of these url modifiers might mean?
(I have Google but did not find any info)

Thanks!